# Javascript dynamic table events not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working out on a Shift or Control key with table which is working in all browsers, but not working in Firefox:

My Javscript code as follows:

```
var lastSelectedRow;
var trs = document.getElementById('tableStudent').tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');

// disable text selection
document.onselectstart = function() {
    return false;
}

function RowClick(currenttr, lock) {
    if (window.event.ctrlKey) {
        toggleRow(currenttr);
    }

    if (window.event.button === 0) {
        if (!window.event.ctrlKey && !window.event.shiftKey) {
            clearAll();
            toggleRow(currenttr);
        }

        if (window.event.shiftKey) {
            alert(lastSelectedRow.rowIndex);
            alert(currenttr.rowIndex);
            selectRowsBetweenIndexes([lastSelectedRow.rowIndex, currenttr.rowIndex])
        }
    }
}

function toggleRow(row) {
    row.className = row.className == 'selected' ? '' : 'selected';
    lastSelectedRow = row;
}

function selectRowsBetweenIndexes(indexes) {
    indexes.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

    for (var i = indexes[0]; i <= indexes[1]; i++) {
        trs[i-1].className = 'selected';
    }
}

function clearAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
        trs[i].className = '';
    }
}
```

Please check the fiddle for details:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rpe/)

It is working in `Chrome`, `opera`, `Edge` but not working in `Firefox`.
Please guide me what changes I make to make it workable in all browsers!

Comment: looks like chrome and opera "support" internet explorer (and edge) non standard `window.event` rubbish. By the way, the code you posted is not enough to work in any browser - how is RowClick called? not evident from your "code" - looked at the fiddle - yeah, that's written in internet explorer specific code, why do chrome and safari pander to MS rubbish

Comment: Was the error in FF not enough to go on `TypeError: window.event is undefined`?

Comment: @Jamiec can you edit the fiddle and give as a response will be helpful. Marking duplicate is not a big deal.

Comment: No, because the duplicate explains *exactly* how to support events in FireFox.

Comment: @Jamiec updated fiddle check this link http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/g8Rpe/121/. But still not working buddy. please help me out!!

Comment: You've not read the linked duplicate properly have you? Where does it say you can just tag on `event` as the *third* parameter? In any case you've just tried to pass `window.event` back as the third parameter in the `onmousedown`.

Comment: Here - http://jsfiddle.net/g8Rpe/123/

Comment: @Jamiec thanks buddy it solved my issue!!